# How to hide a Bootstrap 3 modal using either jQuery or JavaScript inside an AJAX success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `$('#myModal').modal('hide');` inside my AJAX success function in an attempt to hide a [Bootstrap 3 modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

The problem is, my modal isn't hiding. Checking the console I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'modal'

What does this error mean and how can I use either jQuery or JavaScript in my AJAX success function to hide the modal?

**Update and solution:**

It turns out this was a jQuery conflict issue.

I didn't enqueue the bootstrap JavaScript properly. I should have used `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead of referencing the script directly in my document head as advised in the Bootstrap 3 docs. Referencing jQuery and the Bootstrap JS script directly works OK for non-WordPress installs - but conflicts with the built in jQuery used by WP. Apologies for not mentioning I was using WordPress to begin with - I didn't think that info was related.

Thanks to everyone for your help but especially to @gustavo-rubio and @pdoherty926 for the nudge in the right direction.

Comment: How are you creating this modal?

Comment: I'm using the standard mark-up provided by Bootstrap. See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals under "Live demo" - I'm using the mark-up word for word.

Comment: Are you sure the parent div has an id of 'myModal'? The error your getting basically means that $('#myModal') is not a Bootstrap 3 modal plugin.

Comment: @synapze - I'm sure. That was one of the first things I checked.

Comment: So, you're trying to hide a modal that wasn't created using the Twitter JS library?

Comment: I think we are going to need more info. Can you set up an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ or perhaps paste some of the source code in your question?

Comment: Sure - everything is pretty standard as you can see: http://jsfiddle.net/7jM5L/1/

Comment: Could it be my bootstrap JS somehow isn't available inside my AJAX success function? That would cause the error message I'm seeing in the console?

Comment: How exactly does this fiddle support your question? `.modal('hide')` [works there](http://jsfiddle.net/7jM5L/2/)

Comment: Sounds like a jQuery issue to me... which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using WordPress so the jQuery version I'm currently using is 1.10.2

Answer (score 0):

Try this and don`t use custom bootstrap.js without the modal plugin:

```
 $('#myModal').modal({
         show: false
     });
```

Comment: I get the same error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'modal'